# How to get the parent sample generated by a Transaction Controller in JMeter? SampleResult.getParent() returns null

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I have a Thread Group with a Transaction Controller with the "Generate parent sample" checkbox checked and underneath the Transaction Controller is a JSR223 Sampler in which I execute some dummy logging code just to exemplify the problem.

I want to ignore the parent sample and the child sample from all JMeter reporting at runtime.

If, in the JSR223 Sampler I do `SampleResult.setIgnore()`, then the sample generated by the JSR223 Sampler is no longer logged which is ok, but the Parent transaction generated by the Transaction Controller still gets logged with 0 values. This is observable in the View Results Tree listener.

[image]

If I try to get the parent sample, it is null so I can't interact with it in order to ignore it with `.setIgnore()`.

`log.info(SampleResult.getParent())` logs `null` in the log

and

`SampleResult.getParent().setIgnore()` throws error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method setIgnore() on null object`

Is there any way to get and modify the parent sample generated by a Transaction Controller in JMeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, at least not with [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5)

I would recommend using [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) to remove the "unwanted" transactions from the .jtl results file.

Filter Results Tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager).

Alternatively, i.e. if you're generating a [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) and don't want to include some Transaction Controller(s) into the report basing on a certain condition - you could rename the Transaction Controller and use `jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter` and/or `jmeter.reportgenerator.sample_filter` properties to remove the "unwanted" results from the reporting scope.

[image]